# `to the detriment of` means do harm to?

Tags: word-meaning

In merriam-webster.com/dictionary, "to the detriment of" means: in a way that is harmful to.

> The author or authors of this code dedicate any and all copyright interest in this code to the public domain. We make this dedication for the benefit of the public at large and to the detriment of our heirs and successors.

(from the [copyright of sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/copyright.html))

Does the dedication action harm to our heirs and successors?
NO, the dedication action do good to our heirs and successors.
How to explain "to the detriment of" here?

Comment: I think it's kind of a joke.  Dedications usually say that something is *for the benefit of such-and-such*; they very rarely say they are for the detriment of something.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly that it is to the harm of one's heirs.

If I (for example) write a book, then I own the copyright. I can sell copies of the book and prevent anybody else from copying it. After I die my heirs will inherit my copyright and my heirs can continue to benefit from selling the book.

However if put the book into the public domain then anyone can make 
copies. This means the my heirs cannot prevent others from selling copies. This harms my heirs (who can't make money off my book), while benefitting the public at large (who can get my book more cheaply)

Why would anyone do this? It is perhaps because they judge the good done to the public to be worth the harm done to their heirs. The authors my hope for wider distribution of their code than would be possible if they retained copyright. They may finally believe that children should not expect to profit from their parent's work.

Answer (score 0):

In legal contexts, **detriment** can refer to loss or relinquishment of something, including rights under contract and, as we have here, heritable rights.   "Loss" is akin to "harm" but not identical with it.